# Why does `git fetch` empty out my credential file

Tags: git, ubuntu, credentials

1. My git credentials are stored in `/home/user1/.git-credentials`
2. I have a repository with incorrect credentials embedded in its `.git/config` in the form of `https://username:password@example.com/your/project/`
3. If I run `git fetch` on this project, it outputs

   ```
   remote: Verify
   fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://example.com/your/project/'
   ```
4. So far so good. However, git also empties out my `/home/user1/.git-credentials` while leaving the failed credentials in `.git/config` intact (!!)
5. Git version `2.34.1` consistently empties my credentials in the above steps. Question is, why does it happen? and can I prevent such behavior, i.e. do not touch my credential file please

Comment: a temporary authentication failure can also empty the credentials, which is also annoying, but a bit less

Comment: yea, pita... I ended up with `.git-credentials-backup`, which is used to replace `.git-credentials` when the user starts the console

Comment: you can use `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git fetch` to have a detailed output on git command execution, it can contribute to problem understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the error comes from the user, Please verify that you use Your new personal access token from the corresponding field on the top of the page and that you DO NOT COPY PASTE by the error a `Feed token` value in your .git-credentials file